# Drawing a graph in linux

Tags: shell, graph, gnuplot, gnu

I have a file that contains the map between the two entities. I have to plot the x and and Y axis in a graph using linux. The X axis is Time like (12:35:07) and the Y axis will have some integer numbers range (1-14). I need to plot the x and the Y axis using some method that should be called from linux shell script. X axis will have totally around 500 to 800 samples. say (from 12:14:00 to 12:30:00). Can anyone please help me out. I tried using GNUplot, but the graph is not proper. Sample input is given below

```
12:34:58   5
12:35:06   9
12:35:07   14
12:35:07   13
12:35:08   4
12:35:08   5
12:35:17   9
12:35:17   13
12:35:18   14
12:35:19   4
12:35:19   5
```

This is what I have written

```
1 set terminal png
2 set output 'test.png'
3 set xdata time
4 set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
5 set yrange [1:15]
6 plot  "Graph1" using 1:2 title 'data A'
```

The problem I have is since the image has large number of samples (around 700 intervals, I am not able to see each value properly. Also the Y axis is not proper. I need to restrict the Y axis to onlyh 10 values (1-10). Also I need to draw 4 similar graphs and place each graph in each corner (subplot). I have not done the subplot yet in GNUplot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have three main issues right now.  For some of them the issue is not totally clear, so it would help if you could update your question (or make a comment) to clarify, and I can update my response.

**1) Not able to see each of ~700 values properly.**

Here I need a bit of clarification.  I'm assuming you don't want to see each of 700 data points individually, rather you want to be able to get rid of clutter on the x axis which happens when plotting time values.  For this you can use the command

```
set xtics X
```

where X is the interval between tics you want, in this case a number of seconds.  Is this what you want?

You can also use

```
set format x '%M:%S'
```

(or something) if you want to control how the x values are displayed on the axis.

**2) y axis needs to be restricted to 10 values.**

Here also it's not totally clear what you are looking for.  Do you want to scale everything down to be between 1 and 10?  The range of your data presented is 4 to 14, so by subtracting four you can get things between 0 and 10 like this:

```
plot  "Graph1" using 1:($2-4) title 'data A'
```

If you want to constrict an arbitrary y data set to be between 1 and 10, that's a little more tricky:

```
stats "Graph1"
plot "Graph1" using 1:(($2-STATS_min_y)*9/(STATS_max_y-STATS_min_y)+1) title 'data A'
```

The `stats` command gets statistics about a file before you plot it.  The convoluted plot command should scale everything to be between 1 and 10 on the y axis.

**3) You want to have 4 subplots.**

This one is pretty easy.  Before your first plot command, use the command

```
set multiplot layout 2,2
```

This will create a 2x2 grid for your plots.  Every plot command will plot on a new subplot.  Type `help set multiplot` at the gnuplot command line for details on changing the sequence of subplots used.